# Copy and rename files on another directory

Tags: powershell

I want to copy every file from one folder to another folder, and if the file already exists, copy it with a 2 before the extention.  as @BenH told me i used test-path and extension properties but it doesn't copy an already existing file with 2, and i can"t figure out what's wrong

```cs
# script to COPY and RENAME if files already exists
try {
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host " -- process start --"

    $usersPath = "C:\Users\mhanquin\Desktop\test_PS\users\mhanquin"
    $oldPath = "C:\Users\mhanquin\Desktop\test_PS\OLD\mhanquin"

    $folders = dir $usersPath
    $files = dir $oldPath

    foreach ($d in $folders) { 
        $z = test-path $files\$d

        if($z -eq $true){
            $c.basename = $d.basename + "2"
            $c.extension = $d.extension          
            rename-item $userspath\$d -newname $c
            copy-item $userspath\$c $oldpath
        }    
        else{ copy-item $userspath\$d $oldpath }
    }
    Write-Host "---Done---"
} catch {
    Write-Host "ERROR -"$_.Exception.Message
    break
}
```

Comment: I tried to fix your typos and wording, but it's still unclear what you're asking. You told us what you want (or need to achieve) but not, where the problem is.

Comment: If you want to check if the file already exists in the old path, then use an `if` block with `Test-Path` as the conditional. Also, most of your substring logic is unnecessary since the object returned by `Get-ChildItem`/`dir` has the `extension` property

Comment: sorry for my english, it isn't my mothertongue, and it's my first PS script. The issue is that even if the files exists, it is not recognized, i'll try BenH's advices and come back with the output :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more complete solution for what you are attempting to do. Comments inline:

```
$UserPath = "C:\Users\mhanquin\Desktop\test_PS\users\mhanquin"
$OldPath = "C:\Users\mhanquin\Desktop\test_PS\OLD\mhanquin"

$UserItems = Get-ChildItem $UserPath -Recurse

foreach ($UserItem in $UserItems) {
    #Escape the Regex pattern to handle / in paths
    $UserPathRegEx = [Regex]::Escape($usersPath)
    #Use a replace Regex to remove UserPath and leave a relative path 
    $RelativePath = $UserItem.FullName -replace $UserPathRegEx,""
    #Join the Destination and the Relative Path
    $Destination = Join-Path $OldPath $RelativePath
    #Test if it is a directory
    if ($UserItem.PSIsContainer) {
        if (!(Test-Path $Destination)) {
            New-Item $Destination -Type Directory
        }
    } else {
        if (Test-Path $Destination) {
            #Rather than use just a 2, get a timestamp for duplicates
            $TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format MMddhhmm
            #Using subexpression $() to evaluate the variable properties inside a string
            $NewFileName = "$($usersItem.basename).$TimeStamp$($usersItem.extension)"
            #For the rename, join the Directory with the new file name for the new destination
            $NewDestination = Join-Path $($Destination.Directory.fullname) $newFileName
            Rename-Item $Destination -newname $NewDestination
            Copy-Item $UserItem.fullname $Destination
        } else {
            Copy-Item $UserItem.fullname $Destination
        }       
    }

}
```